# Regex python: end of the string in a list

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the following regex in python:

```
http://www\..+\..*?[$/]
```

It should catch:

```
http://blabla.com/test/ => http://blabla.com/ # Work 
http://blabla.com => http://blabla.com # Doesn't work
```

I suppose it's because of the `$` int the `[ ]`. How can I make an end of the string in a list like that?

Comment: Since neither of your examples has a `www.` and the regex does, neither should match. Please make your question consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, you either have a slash at the end, or you don't:

```
http://www\..+\..*?/?$
```